# How are values passed in ?: conditional ternary operator switch

Tags: pine-script

Trying to convert the following statement to Python

```
var down = 1
down := down != 1 and close < (showRange ? upRange : upTrend) ? 1 : down == 1 and close > downTrend ? -1 : down
```

The Pine-script documentation does not mention how (down != 1) or (down == 1) work in this context, nor does it explain where the : down at the end gets it value from.

Here is a simplified Pinescript code with line numbers:

```
1. var down = 1
2. cond5 = close < (showRange ? upRange : upTrend)
3. cond4 = close > downTrend
4. cond6 = down != 1 and cond5
5. down := cond6 ? 1 : cond4 ? -1 : down
```

On line 4 down != 1 seems redundant, but if I remove it the output is changed.

Any idea how the value of down is passed around?

Comment: If you do not understand how the "black box" works, you should use the debugging tips [Debugging](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/Debugging.html)  

IMHO the nuance lies in declaring a global variable `var down=1`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert any [ternary](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#op_%7Bquestion%7D%7Bcolon%7D) (`?:`) construction to an `if-then-else` on [this website](https://converter.website-dev.eu/)

**First example**

```
var down = 1
down := down != 1 and close < (showRange ? upRange : upTrend) ? 1 : down == 1 and close > downTrend ? -1 : down
```

becomes this in pseudo python code

```
if (down != 1 and close < (showRange) {
    down = upRange
} else {
    if (upTrend)) {
        down = 1
    } else {
        if (down == 1 and close > downTrend) {
            down = -1
        } else {
            down = down
        }
    }
}
```

*The result of the entire ternary construct is assigned to `down`,*
*but in Python that becomes embedded into the `if-then-else` statement)*

**Second example**

```
((up != 1) and (close > (showRange ? downRange : downTrend))) ? 1 : (((up == 1) and (close < upTrend)) ? -1 : up)
```

becomes this in pseudo python code

```
if showRange {
    close_showRange = downRange
} else {
    close_showRange = downTrend
}

if (up != 1) and (close > close_showRange) {
    1
} else {
    if (up == 1) and (close < upTrend) {
        -1
    } else {
        up
    }
}
```

*The result of the entire ternary construct is not assigned to any variable here,*
*because your example didn't do that either.*

Comment: In 1st example down=1, so both if statements don't work since "down!=1" is always true and "down==1" is always true. Pine-script is doing something else under the hood. and this reflect what I see, In pine I get a value for down, and in Python incorrect values.

Comment: Pine-script has two way of handling ternary statement, like an if statement or like a switch statement and this is a switch.

Comment: No, it's not a switch statement. Pine doesn't have a switch statement concept (yet). It are nested if-then-else statements. Your comment on the 1st example is incorrect. Just follow the pseudo python code I posted. It follows different paths in that statement, depending on down being 1 or not.

Comment: From the manual: If condition is true then the ternary operator will return result1, otherwise it will return result2. A combination of conditional operators can build constructs similar to switch statements in other languages. For example:
isintraday ? red : isdaily ? green : ismonthly ? blue : na - https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#conditional-operator-and-the-iff-function

Comment: The switch statement works differently as I believe it passes the returned value around, I did try your solution and in Python it doesn't return the same results that the Pine-script does.

Comment: I must disagree. It's not a switch. It does not pass the returned value around. An important concept in Pine is that the script is executed on every bar. That's a big difference with Python. Maybe that's the core of your issue.

Comment: I added a more simplified code snippet above removing the switch out of the equation, it proves that the value for "down" is changed by Pinescript outside the scope of the code snippet using some magic, Please see above.

Comment: It's not magic. It's the [Execution Model](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/Quickstart_guide.html#execution-model-of-pine-scripts) of Pine Script that's very different from other languages.

Comment: I finally discovered what the magic is in Pine-script -
"var is the keyword used for assigning one-time initializing of the variable.
Normally, a syntax of assignment of variables, which doesn't include the keyword var, results in the value being overwritten with every update of the data.
Contrary to that, when assigning variables with the keyword var, they can "keep the state" despite the data updating, only changing it when conditions within if-expressions are met." Tiny little detail... that changes the known universe of programming